# If $e$ (Euler's constant) $= (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ as $n$ approaches infinity, why is $e^x$ not equal to $e$? if x equals any number, real or not real.

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity, fake-proofs

If $e$ (Euler's constant) $= (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ as $n$ approaches infinity, why is $e^x$ not equal to $e$ if x equals any number, real or not real.

Let r = any real number

I think that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{rn} = e^r$, and $rn = n$ when $n$ approaches infinity, so $e^r$ should equal $e$.

Also, $0*infinity=1$, so if both sides are raised to the $e$, you get 1$*$e^infinity=$e$, so $e$^infinity should also equal $e$.

Could anyone tell me what I did wrong here?

Comment: Also, if 0 * infinity = 1 or 1^infinty = e,         e^0 * e^infinty = e^1

Comment: 2n/n does not become 1 because both n and 2n approach infinity

Comment: so we can also use 0.6=0.2 so $2=6$ that makes perfect sense acc to you??

Comment: As @mathreadler said, $2n$ and $n$ both go to infinity, but at different rates. This different rate affects the value of the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the formal definition for limit to explain this exactly, but here's an intuitive way to see it.

The expression 
$$
\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n}
$$
whose limit is $e$ is subtle. The sum inside the parentheses approaches $1$, which tends to make the limit $1$. But the exponent grows to infinity. So you are raising  numbers nearer and nearer to  $1$ to higher and higher powers. The result might be anything between $1$ and infinity, depending on how those conflicting tendencies fight it out. In this case the compromise turns out to be $e \approx 2.718$.

Now on to your question. 
Very loosely speaking, $2n$ grows to infinity twice as fast as $n$ does. So the exponent in
$$
\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{2n}
$$
is making the limit bigger faster than the decrease in $1/n$ is making it smaller. To see why the actual limit is $e^2$ simply rewrite
$$
\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{2n}=
\left[ \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n} \right]^2 .
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} (1+\frac 1n)^n = \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} (1+\frac 1{2n})^{2n} = e$

Which is different from $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} (1+\frac 1n)^{2n}= e^2$

While we are here.

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} (1+\frac 2n)^{n}= e^2$

Answer (score 1):

Just as $\lim \frac{2x}{x} \neq \lim \frac{x}{x},$ despite both fractions being formally $\infty/\infty.$ It’s not enough to notice that numerator and denominator are both $\infty$. You need to know they go to infinity at the same rate, to conclude that the ratio is one.

Similarly in the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n},$ if your exponent approaches infinity twice as fast as your base’s discrepancy from $1$ approaches zero, that must be accounted for. Those rates must be exactly the same for the resulting limit to be exactly $e.$